# Why can I still write in my firebase even with a rule that forbids it?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've written the followings rules in my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,        
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === 'MY_ADMIN_USER_UID' "
    }
}
```

where 'MY_ADMIN_USER_UID' is a string that represent the uid of the admin user in my Authentication Firebase.

I also used the following Kotlin code to connect to Authentication Firebase:

```
private var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("xxx@gmail.com", "xxx")
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if(task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d("Authentication", "signInWithCustomToken: success")
                    }else{
                        Log.d("Authentication", "signInWithCustomToken: Failed")
                    }
                }
```

With this code, I can connect to my authentication database and I receive the "signInWithCustomToken: success" log. I can write in my realtime database while connected.
But now I can still write in the database even if I don't use `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` or if I use `firebaseAuth.signOut()`. Whereas according to my rules I can only write data if I am logged in with the correct uid.
I'd like to understand this behavior and only grant read access to users with the correct email/password.

Comment: The Firebase Android SDK will remember your authentication state even after closing and reopening the app. Have you made sure that whenever you observe this behaviour that you are actually logged out (`firebaseAuth.currentUser` should be null)? Are the rules you provided the only rules in your database and they are active (not a draft)?

Comment: So you basically say that you can write to the database even if your user is not authenticated? How did you check that?

Comment: I think I didn't checked if I was actually signed out. It works as expected now.